# Angular ng-class not rendering correctly HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-class

I'm new to AngularJS and i have the next issue. I'm calculating my CSS class of the body tag with ng-class like this.

```
<body ng-class="getCSSclassBody(Sucursal.SucursalEmpresaRubroNombre)">
```

The thing is that sometimes is rendering the HTML correctly, but sometimes class is empty. It seems like HTML is rendered faster than the evaluation of the function in the controller. Can anyone guide me on how to solve this problem?

```
    $scope.getCSSclassBody = function(rubro)
{
    if(rubro == 'Vestimenta'){
        var index = getRandomInt(0,arrayVestimenta.length);
        return arrayVestimenta[index];
    }
    else if(rubro == 'Peluquería'){
        var index = getRandomInt(0,arrayPeluqueria.length);
        return arrayPeluqueria[index];
    }
    else if(rubro == 'Gastronomía'){
        var index = getRandomInt(0,arrayGastronomia.length);
        return arrayGastronomia[index];
    }
    else if(rubro == 'Rentadora'){
        var index = getRandomInt(0,arrayRentadora.length);
        return arrayRentadora[index];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advice.

Comment: What do you mean by not rendering correctly... Does the class stay empty, or does it just take a while to catch up.

Comment: can you post `getCSSclassBody` function here?

Comment: @Jorg What i mean is that CSS class is not being load, so HTML instead of rendering a background as i want, stays white

Comment: @MarBVI just created plunk for your reference. I think this might be helpful to you here is link to plunk : http://plnkr.co/edit/lBcTlyvvEQPEgFC2FvCC?p=preview

Comment: Please make sure that value of "Sucursal.SucursalEmpresaRubroNombre" is defined in ur controller and try to print the value of "rubro" in console. I think it will give undefined whenever ur HTML is not rendering.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya ty for your time but it was not much help for me, i can't still make it work

Comment: @Dipen yes it is. Sucursal is load by an $http.post called, once that is loaded, Sucursal is available. The problem occurs when the server takes longer to respond, ng-class is evaluated later, but HTML is already rendered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number generated by `getRandomInt(0, arrayRentadora.length)` is equal to `arrayRentadora.length`, then `arrayRentadora[index]` will be `undefined`.

For example, if `arrayRentadora = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"]`, the length is 4, and `arrayRentadora[4]` will be `undefined`.

To ensure you always choose a value from the array, you want this instead:

```
var index = getRandomInt(0, arrayRentadora.length - 1);
```

Comment: @j.witter GENIUS!! can't beleive such silly mistake...all day trying to fix this!! Thanks :)